# running test Case using OCUnit not working?

Tags: iphone, unit-testing, ocunit

when run the target for test cases nothing is happening instead it is showing warning message

warning: Skipping tests; the iPhoneSimulator platform does not currently support application-hosted tests (TEST_HOST set).

i am using xcode 3.2.5 and iOS4.2 ..........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can't run unit tests on the Simulator, you need to run them on the device itself.

**Edited to add**

Times have changed!

Comment: u sure i did not find that instruction in iphone documentation.

Comment: Logic tests run on the simulator but application tests run on the device https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/135-Unit_Testing_Applications/unit_testing_applications.html

Comment: Also http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/12/sample-iphone-application-with-complete.html

Answer (score 1):

*Original answer from Dec. 29, 2010:*

Ignore Apple's distinction between "Logic tests" and "Application tests". Use [GTM](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/wiki/iPhoneUnitTesting) instead. You'll have one testing target that works on either the simulator or the device, and can be debugged without additional setup.

*New answer:*

Xcode's built-in unit testing has come a long way since then. I've switched from GTM back to OCUnit. See http://qualitycoding.org/xcode-unit-testing/